# C#: ViewState does not catch exception in source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I was wondering as to why my try catch block is not effective, when I try to assign a custom object(non serializable) to Viewstate.

A doubt as to why exception is not thrown while assigning a non-serializable object in the source code file itself.

Why it is being handled in Global.asax?

Well, here are a few snapshots which concerns my doubt:

[image]

[image]

***Exception Description:***
[image]

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: @CodeCaster Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.